# AES - Difference in Decrypted data

Tags: java, csv, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have developed a utility for encryption and decryption of file with AES Encryption and handshaking between receiver and sender is done under RSA PKI Encryption.

Now, I have following chain of steps:

1. Upload CSV.
2. Generate hash of content with private key of sender.
3. Sign the Hash with private key of sender.
4. Generate Symmetric key and IV.
5. Encrypt the actual csv with Symmetric key using IV. with public key of receiver.
6. Encrypt Symmetric key and IV.

Now at the receiver end:

1. Decrypt hash with public key of sender.
2. Verify signature with public key of sender.
3. Decrypt Symmetric key and IV with private key of receiver.
4. Decrypt actual csv with symmetric key and iv..
5. Regenerate hash of decrypted file content and match with decrypted hash.

Now, my all the steps are working as per requirement but hashes are not matched...
when I take the diff of plain text csv and decrypted csv. They have a difference of 1st line only.

**FIRST LINE OF PLAIN-TEXT CSV**

```
ICI,ICI-DIV1,,,,,,,,,,[Space]
[Next Line]
```

**FIRST LINE OF DECRYPTED CSV**

```
ICIŽICI-DIV1,,,,,,,,,,[Content of second line and so on..]
```

**Now you can see the difference is of only first line a space and line separator at the end of line and the 4th character is quite different in both.**

I think its because of IV or any sort of line separation required..
However, the 4th character is some sort of encoding issue.

can someone identify and suggest?

**ENCRYPTION CODE USED FOR FILE ENCRYPTION USING SYMMETRIC KEY**

```
// Read content from CSV file..
    public String readCsv ( String file ) {

        // String builder to read all lines in one string..
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Line variable to hold each line data..
        String line = EMPTY_STRING;

        try {

            // Read CSV file.. 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) );

            // Read each line and append it to String builder
            while ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
                sb.append( line );
                sb.append( "\n" );
            }
            br.close();
        }

        // In case of exception..
        catch ( Exception e ) {

            System.out.println( "Exception in reading csv = " + e );

        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

String encryptedPaymentFile = AESEncryptFile(  contentOfFile.getBytes( "UTF-8" ) , AESParams.getKey(), AESParams.getIV() );

String contentOfFile = readCsv( encryptedFilePath ) ;

// Function to encrypt the file with AES Algorithm..
    public static String AESEncryptFile( byte[] input, SecretKeySpec key, byte[] initVector )  {

        // Initialize Cipher variable and encryption variable..
        Cipher cipher = null;
        byte[] cipherInBytes = null;

        try {

            /* 1. Set the cipher to AES Algorithm, CBC Mode and PKC5 Padding scheme..
             * 2. Set the Cipher mode to encryption using key and initVector..
             * 3. Get the encrypted text 
             * 4. return the cipher text with base64 encoding..
             */
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" );
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec( initVector );
            cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec );
            cipherInBytes = cipher.doFinal( input );

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( cipherInBytes );

        }

        // In case of exception..
        catch ( Exception e ) {

            System.out.println( "Exception in Main File Encryption " + e ); 

        }

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( cipherInBytes );

    }
```

**DECRYPTION CODE**

```
public static String decrypt ( byte[] cipherText, SecretKeySpec key, byte[] IV ) throws Exception
    {
        //Get Cipher Instance
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" );

        //Create IvParameterSpec
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec( IV );


        //Initialize Cipher for DECRYPT_MODE
        cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec );

        byte[] decodedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode( cipherText );

        String decryptedData = new String( cipher.doFinal( decodedData ) );

        return decryptedData;
    }

symmetricKey = RSADecrypt( keyFileInBytes, "Key");
            initializationVector = RSADecrypt( ivFileInBytes, "Key");

            if ( symmetricKey.equalsIgnoreCase( EMPTY_STRING ) || 
                    initializationVector.equalsIgnoreCase( EMPTY_STRING ) ) {

                System.out.println( "Decryption of IV / KEY Failed .. " );

                generateOutput( "Decryption of .Key files Failed.." , true);

                return;

            } 
            System.out.println( "Key and IV has been decrypted.."); 

SecretKeySpec symmKey = new SecretKeySpec( symmetricKey.getBytes(), "AES" );

            decryptedMainFile = decrypt( encryptedFileInBytes, symmKey, initializationVector.getBytes() );
```

Comment: Looks like an encoding Problem. Always use the encoding parameter to avoid such issues whenever you create readers or writers.

Comment: Can you guide me with a code snippet please?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? I’m asking because Java 11 added some methods that would make the code more concise.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you do not want to apply any processing to the CSV data, just encrypt/decrypt? Then all encoding problems can be entirely avoided by just encrypting the binary data as is without converting to text and back again. Just read all bytes from the connection and encrypt directly. As for the encoding: use `BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`. Make sure to use the correct Charset and use it every time when binary data is converted to text or back (another example is the call to `new String()`).

Comment: @Axel Thanks a lot for your prompt response. I appreciate that. Can you please let me know what do you mean by **read all bytes from the connection?** you mean I shall read data from csv as provided in your code snippet and pass it to the encrypt function?

Comment: I have updated the csv reading function to something like this --> ```try {
      
      // Read CSV file.. 
      //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) );
      BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      // Read each line and append it to String builder
      while ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
       sb.append( line );
       sb.append( "\n" );
      }
      br.close();
     }```

Comment: @Axel I tried your solution and it resolved my issue and now the file is decrypting perfectly. Just one more issue that the actual plain text file was 23 Kb and the decrypted one is 22 Kb in size. However there is no difference in the files. Any specific reason?

Comment: I’d say that’s not possible. Have you checked the exact size in bytes on the command line? From my experience for sizes reported by windows explorer are sometimes dubious.

Comment: Well might be. But not issue might be its because of the some byte shrinking as per array sizes during encryption decryption